# Azure backup region: website DataBase

Tags: azure

I'm deploying an eCommerce site for my customer in spain. So, my first idea was to deploy it to the Azure Nortwest region.

The problem is that, even with the SLA of 99.99%, there could happen that the whole Azure datacenter would broke-down. (The same as the Amazon S3 services that went down for severeal hours some months ago).

My question is: How to protect against this eventual problem? I know that I can change my DNS C-Name to change the endpoint website, but it takes a lot of time to propagate DNS changes, and I must have a very-current backup of the database to be able to restore it into another server.
I know I can use traffic manager too, but I still have the problem with the database....

Which is the best aproach to solve this problem? 
Also, I have some doubts about if this is reasonable to take this into consideration for a medium sized company. 
Is anyone doing this, and is happy with the solution? 8·)

thanks in advance for your help,
luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Data Sync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh456371.aspx) is a great way to synchronize the data between Azure SQL Databases.  It works across Data Centers as well as regions.  Using SQL Data Sync you could create a second database in another data center and synchronize the data between the two databases.  There will likely be a period of time that you are exposed to loss however as the time between automatic syncs currently can't be lower that five minutes.